# sudo shell script mkdir

Tags: shell, sudo, mkdir

myscript.sh is

```
#/!bin/sh
mkdir -p $1
cp -p a.txt ./$1
cp b.txt /usr
```

If I invoke it with sudo ./myscript.sh, the directory $1 is owned by root, so the user can't modify a.txt (which is a problem). I could change the script to

```
#/!bin/sh
mkdir -p $1
cp -p a.txt ./$1
sudo cp b.txt /usr
```

and invoke with just ./myscript.sh but I get the impression this is bad practice. How to proceed in the general case, where I don't know the user, so chown doesn't help?

Comment: You can get the current user from the environment variable $USER. Hence, you can use chown inside your script.

Comment: @jitendra: I can set `USER=anybody` before invoking the script, and the file will be `chown`'d to the wrong user.

Comment: You should not be copying plain files into `/usr`; it should only contain directories in the normal course of events.  Why do you want a `/usr/b.txt` file at all?  It looks to me a bit as if you have two separate tasks being bundled into one, incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

`SUDO_USER` environment variable is set by `sudo` to the name of the user who invoked `sudo`. You can use it for `chown`.

As of bad practices, you don't check anything and your `$1` argument substitution is broken for filenames with spaces. If that much doesn't matter, should you care for the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You should add this line

```
chmod ug+rw a.txt
```

With this one, the user will have read/write permissions on 'a.txt'.

Comment: Giving world-write permissions to a file is usually a bad idea.